# How do I move files by looking at part of a file name

Tags: linux, macos, unix, thumbnails

My web application creates multiple image thumbnail files when users upload images.

I want to separate original images and thumbnail images. Thumbnail images contain 'crop-smart' in their file name.

For example, original image is watermelon.jpg, then thumbnail's name is watermelon_jpg_120x120_crop-smart.jpg.

How do I find by say 'crop-smart' and either move them to the different folder or delete them?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard [file globbing](http://tomecat.com/jeffy/tttt/glob.html) will do this, the exact details may vary depending out which shell you are running but for your exact problem, it should be the same:

```
mv -- *_crop-smart.jpg /path/to/new/folder/
```

(This will also work if you have spaces in the filename)

***Note** the `--` signals to `mv` that no more option switches will follow, so even if filenames look like options, `mv` won't get confused.*

Comment: Hm, it's not working on my mac osx. It doesn't seem to recognize * in commands.

Comment: Get rid of the quotes. I didn't mean for those to be in there. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @DavidL: Also, if this is intended for OSX, you need to change your question and the tags.

Comment: @kbyrd it works fine with spaces, the parameters are expanded by the shell and put nicely into an array for `execve` (try `strace -ve trace=process /bin/echo *` for fun and proof)

Comment: For some reason, this gave me "mv: invalid option -- 1" for both centos linux and mac osx unix. Ended up using 'find . -name "*_crop-smart.jpg" -exec mv {} /path/to/new/folder \;'

Comment: @DavidL: I bet you'll find a filename starting with `-1` or `--1` in your directory. In that case, you need to prefix `--`, showing in edited answer

Comment: Awesome~ Thank you kbyrd and sehe

Comment: sehe: Thanks for the cleanup, I always forget about '--'.